# Updating state does not rerender a mapped variable

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a constant which maps through an array of objects and returns a list of components to be rendered:

```
    const displayUniversities = universitiesToDisplay.map(
        (item: UniversityModel) => {
            return (
                <UniversityCard university={item} key={item['Institution']['S']} />
            );
        }
    );
```

the array `universitiesToDisplay` is using setState, which I am trying to update when the user selects an option in a dropdown which is also a component:

```
<UniversitySorting handleSort={handleSort} />
```

The `handleSort` is a function which would take the event coming from inside the component and call a sort function to update the list to be displayed.
For brievety with this question I am just updating the array without doing any checks on what option they have clicked:

```
const handleSort = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setUniversitiesToDisplay(
        sortUniversities(universitiesToDisplay, 'ascending')
    );
};
```

when I console log `universitiesToDisplay` after doing the update it indeed prints out the correct array in the correct order however the `displayUniversities` map function never gets rerendered. 
I already have another functionality where I am doing almost the exact same thing, i.e: a search function that calls my backend and updates the list in the same way and it gets rerendered perfectly.
In the HTML I am simply displaying it like this:

```
<div>{displayUniversities}</div>
```

So I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the code of `sortUniversities`? `Array.prototype.sort` doesn't return a new array, it returns the original array _mutated_ which doesn't play well with setState by default.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yeah I am using sort but I managed to find an alternate solution, I'll close the issue.